# XLookup Not Working on Office 365

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have Office 365 and I still can't use xlookup.  When I manually type it in, I get #NAME?.  How can I get this feature? The last answer was from a year ago...

Comment: Have you tried checking for updates?

Comment: I fully uninstalled and reinstalled Office 365. Wouldn't that automatically give me any updates?

Comment: and you are puttng an `=` in front of `xlookup` right? it should pop out as a suggested formula as you are typing. Otherwise, you have an issue with the actual formula usage and not because you don't have the formula available. Perhaps update with this  question with your formula syntax...

Comment: I am definitely including the =. The only suggestions I get are XIRR, XNPN and XOR. That's how I know it's not an available option. The formula I'm using is formatted as such: =xlookup(p14,f2:f7,G2:G7)

Comment: @Loretta a fresh install should update during install, but check for updates just in case: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/install-office-updates-2ab296f3-7f03-43a2-8e50-46de917611c5

Comment: Navigate to `File => Account` On the Product Information side, under `About Excel`, share the Version, Build and **Channel** information.  If you don't have **Current Channel**, that feature may not yet have been installed.

Comment: When I go into About Excel, I see Version 1908 (Build 11929.20752 Click-to-Run) and Semi-annual Channel. Does that indicate whether I am in the Current Channel or not?

Comment: It indicates that you are **NOT** in the Current Channel.  But version 1908 was from last year. And there have been updates to the Semi-annual channel this year. Probably you need to talk to your company IT person to see if you can get a more current version of Excel. Your version is from May 2020.

Comment: Thanks so much!! That was super helpful!!